# How to allow python to not import multiple times?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, python-import

I have a large number of import statements (with prints for debug...) for my code:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function, unicode_literals
import os, sys, struct, json, time, socket
print("start import BS")
from BS import run_BS  # custom library
print("end import BS")
print("Import 1")
print("Import 2")
import numpy as np
print("Import 3")
import platform
import datetime
from posixpath import join as pjoin
print("Import 4")
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
import matplotlib
import tkinter
print("Import 5")
print("Import 6")
print("Import 7")
from send_tune_request import tune
print("Import  8")
print("Import 9")
```

and the code structure is roughly:

```
class ed_bs:
    def __init__(self, check=False, test_mode=False):
        curr_BS_proc = Process(target=run_BS, args=(a, b, c))
    def main_loop(self):
         while 1:
             pass  # run forever...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    e_d = ed_bs(check=True)
    test_mode = True
    if test_mode:
        test_start_thread = Process(target=tune)
        test_start_thread.setDaemon = True
        test_start_thread.start()
```

The print statements look like as follows:

```
start import BS
end import BS
Import 1
Import 2
Import 3
Import 4
Import 5
Import 6
Import 7
Import  8
Import 9
start import BS
end import BS
Import 1
Import 2
Import 3
Import 4
Import 5
Import 6
Import 7
Import  8
Import 9
start import BS
end import BS
Import 1
Import 2
Import 3
Import 4
Import 5
Import 6
Import 7
Import  8
Import 9
```

I'm guessing that it's printing three times because there's 3 processes in this flow (the `__main__` process, `tune`, and `run_BS`), but neither BS nor send_tune_request import the `__file__` file so I am a little confused. The imports take a long time (`run_BS` has Tensforflow trace compiling) and use a lot of memory to import everything thrice over three processors so I'd like to limit imports more appropriately.

Why are the import taking a long time and how do I make everything import only once?

Thanks for the help.

EDIT: BS.py looks something like the below:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function, unicode_literals
import os, sys, struct, json, time
from posixpath import join as pjoin
from termcolor import colored
import numpy as np
import scipy.signal as sig
import tensorflow as tf
import platform
import tensorflow_probability as tfp

def run_BS():
    bs = BS()
    while 1:
        bs.process_data()

class BS:
    def process_data(self):
        self.tf_process_1()
        self.tf_process_2()
        self.non_tf_process()

    @tf.function
    def tf_process_1(self):
        tf.cast()
        ...

    @tf.function
    def tf_process_2(self):
        tf.cast()
        ...

    def non_tf_process(self):
        x = np.zeros(100)
        x = x+1
        ...
```

Comment: Most modules shouldn't do much more than define read-only values like constants, classes, and functions.  You haven't shown the definition of `run_BS`, so it's hard to say what you are trying to do or how to do it better.

Comment: @chepner updated the main post. run_BS is simply a wrapper around the BS class so that the class can run in a separate process.

Comment: Python imports every module once only and adds them to sys.modules. Only if a module can't be found there, it will be imported from sys.path. Of cause this doesn't apply to your print statements ...

Comment: You are presumably on Windows, in which case you may like to research why the `if __name__ == '__main__'` is required when using `multiprocessing` (and the implications for the imports being performed by your module). In short, you need to move the imports into the `if` to not be performed three times (it should also be noted that `sys.modules` doesn't span processes, as they are handled by different interpreters, so the import has to be performed each time)